# Conclusion from fraction in sample to fraction in whole population

Tags: probability, sampling

Of 1974 Americans surveyed, 101 said that they believe that astrology is scientific. What is the probability that more than 6% of Americans believe that astrology is scientific?

Comment: Please check https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This is a tough one to answer correctly even for people who are very good at math, because to apply any mathematics at all requires adding at least two pieces of information to the question: (1) how the survey was taken and (2) what your beliefs were *before* the survey results were revealed to you.  Could you include this information in your post?

Comment: Whuber, I know that I should have mentioned this earlier, but it's actually a homework question. That was all that was given to me. Thanks!